# Why is SignedRegionDistance always returning zeroes?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

I have a simple parabolic region:

```
 reg = ImplicitRegion[
      x <= 1/2 && y <= Sqrt[1/2 - x]/2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

It appears to be behaving properly:

```
Region[reg]

RegionMember[reg, {.1, .9}]

RegionMember[reg, {.1, .01}]
```

Now, I create a curried RegionDistanceFunction:

```
srd = SignedRegionDistance[reg]
```

It returns zeroes that I don't expect:

```
srd[{.9, .9}] (*0*)

srd /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {64, 2}] (* 64 zeroes *)
```

However, if I use the two-argument form of SignedRegionDistance, it appears to be working properly.

```
SignedRegionDistance[reg, {.1, .01}] (*-0.01*)

SignedRegionDistance[reg, {.1, .9}] (*0.555521*)
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug.

Using various representations for a [`Disk`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html)

```
regions = Prepend[RegionConvert[Disk[], #] & /@
   {"Implicit", "Mesh", "Parametric"}, Disk[]]

(* {Disk[{0, 0}], 
 ImplicitRegion[\[FormalX]^2 + \[FormalY]^2 <= 1, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}], 
 RegionConvert[Disk[{0, 0}], "Mesh"], 
 ParametricRegion[{{Cos[\[FormalX]] \[FormalY], \[FormalY] Sin[\[FormalX]]}, 
   0 <= \[FormalX] <= 2 π && 
    0 <= \[FormalY] <= 1}, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]} *)
```

The "Mesh" form failed to create a valid region

```
RegionQ /@ regions

(* {True, True, False, True} *)
```

Working only with valid regions,

```
regions2 = Select[regions, RegionQ];

srd = SignedRegionDistance /@ regions2
```

[image]

```
#[{0.9, 0.9}] & /@ srd

{0.272792, 0., 0.}
```

The [`RegionDistanceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistanceFunction.html) only worked for the "special" region type. Whereas,

```
SignedRegionDistance[#, {0.9, 0.9}] & /@ regions2

(* {0.272792, 0.272792, 0.272792} *)
```

works for all three representations

Comment: Thanks. I’ll report the bug.

Answer (score 4):

Two another approachs indicate that this is a bug.( one is `DiscretizeRegion` the `reg`, another is calculate the sign distance from the `RegionBoundary` of the reg.

```
Clear[signdist1, signdist2];
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x <= 1/2 && y <= Sqrt[1/2 - x]/2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
signdist1 = SignedRegionDistance[DiscretizeRegion@reg];
signdist2 = (-1)^Boole@RegionMember[reg]@#*
    RegionDistance[RegionBoundary[reg]]@# &;
{signdist1@{.1, .01}, signdist1@{.1, .9}}
{signdist2@{.1, .01}, signdist2@{.1, .9}}
```

> `{-0.01, 0.555521}`

> `{-0.01, 0.555521}`

Comment: Thanks. I’ll report the bug.